# Requests vs Curl

Tags: python-3.x, curl, python-requests

I have an application running on AWS that makes a request to a page to pull meta tags using `requests`. I'm finding that page is allowing curl requests, but not allowing requests from the `requests` library.

Works:

```
curl https://www.seattletimes.com/nation-world/mount-st-helens-which-erupted-41-years-ago-starts-reopening-after-covid-closures/
```

Hangs Forever:

```
imports requests
requests.get('https://www.seattletimes.com/nation-world/mount-st-helens-which-erupted-41-years-ago-starts-reopening-after-covid-closures/')
```

What is the difference between curl and requests here? Should I just spawn a curl process to make my requests?

Comment: Try to set `User-Agent` header with `headers=` parameter.

Comment: @AndrejKesely funny enough i tried that with a browser UA and it did not work. but with the UA `curl/7.61.1` it does (even in python)

Answer (score 2):

Either of the agents below do indeed work. One can also use the user_agent module (located on pypi [here](https://pypi.org/project/user_agent/)) to generate random and valid web user agents.

```py
import requests

agent = (
    "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) "
    "AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) "
    "Chrome/85.0.4183.102 Safari/537.36"
)

# or can use
# agent = "curl/7.61.1"

url = ("https://www.seattletimes.com/nation-world/"
       "mount-st-helens-which-erupted-41-years-ago-starts-reopening-after-covid-closures/")

r = requests.get(url, headers={'user-agent': agent})
```

Or, using the user_agent module:

```py
import requests
from user_agent import generate_user_agent

agent = generate_user_agent()

url = ("https://www.seattletimes.com/nation-world/"
       "mount-st-helens-which-erupted-41-years-ago-starts-reopening-after-covid-closures/")

r = requests.get(url, headers={'user-agent': agent})
```

To further explain, requests sets a default user agent [here](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/master/requests/utils.py#L808), and the seattle times is blocking this user agent. However, with python-requests one can easily change the header parameters in the request as shown above.

To illustrate the default parameters:

```py
r = requests.get('https://google.com/')
print(r.request.headers)
>>> {'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.25.1', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Connection': 'keep-alive'}
```

vs. the updated header parameter

```py
agent = "curl/7.61.1"
r = requests.get('https://google.com/', headers={'user-agent': agent})
print(r.request.headers)
>>>{'user-agent': 'curl/7.61.1', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Connection': 'keep-alive'}
```