# requests.get isn't returning a result for the CME website

Tags: python, python-requests

When I run the following code, it never returns a result. Am I missing something like a header?

```
page = requests.get("https://www.cmegroup.com/trading/price-limits.html#equityIndex",timeout=300)
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: There is no error message, the function call never returns.

Answer (score 2):

Change the user agent for the request as follows:

```py
import requests

agent = (
    "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) "
    "AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) "
    "Chrome/85.0.4183.102 Safari/537.36"
)

url = "https://www.cmegroup.com/trading/price-limits.html#equityIndex"
r = requests.get(url, headers={'user-agent': agent})
```

Can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67591766/requests-vs-curl/67613139#67613139) for explanation, the site is most likely blocking python-requests headers